# Always On VPN Windows 10 Multiple Certificates

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-10

I have a working setup with Server 2012 R2 and Windows 10.

The only issue I have is the auto connect. It tries to auto connect but as there are 2 user certificates it fails saying action is required. Selecting the correct certificate then completes the connection without issue.

Is there a way to code into the VPN Profile, only use a certificate template, or issued by this server or something along those lines?

The other certificate in question is being issued from our Lync server..... Not sure why it is being issued or if its needed. I am also looking into if I can stop it being issued. I've tried deleting it (Lync still works) however it gets regenerated the next time I sign into Lync.

Comment: Yes. The certificates can be selected in the advanced details of the VPN connection. They can be filtered by root CA, server name, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll do that enabling certificate filtering in your EAP configuration. To do this, right-click the properties of your VPN connection and choose Properties. Click on the Security tab and then click the Properties button below the EAP drop-down list. Click Configure next to Select Authentication Method and then click the Advance button. Here you can choose the specific CA you want the certificate to be issued by, and optionally choose a specific EKU the certificate must contain. Once that works, export the EAP configuration and update your ProfileXML with the new settings. :)